# ImageMagick SVG to PNG problems

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png, imagick

I am trying to get SVG to PNG conversion working on Amazon Linux. I already have everything working on Ubuntu but I can't seem to get Inkscape installed on Amazon Linux to have a better renderer.

Has anybody been able to install Inkscape on Amazon and/or had the problem? Has anybody had problems with the SVG to PNG conversion producing blank images?

Also with Imagick I read and wrote out the same file and the written out file has errors. There is an error with this code obviously: `<g style="</g>`.

Read in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="728" height="90">
<g></g>
</svg>
```

It wrote out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="728" height="90">
<g style="">
<g style="</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Thanks,
twosik

Comment: I tried everything. I think the reason for the blank image is because it is invalid SVG obviously. I don't know why there is that invalid tag stuck in there.

Comment: Why not post some code? Or do you expect people to debug this using the Force?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to convert SVG to PNG try **[svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport)**, a tiny cross-platform command line tool I have made for SVG conversion.

Comment: Would of been nice to have your library when this was an issue. I now use a javascript library (svgcanvas) to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say "tiny" considering it uses phantomjs internally